# Marketing Cloud Connect in Sandbox when previously set up

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I attempted to set up marketing cloud connect with API users between a new child BU and our sandbox CRM environment. It looks like sandbox could have been previously connected as the permission sets were already created.

I was able to connect in Marketing Cloud but in CRM when the wizard option is supposed to appear, there is only the option to connect to Marketing Cloud. After logging into the Marketing Cloud API user from CRM the page just refreshes and doesn't go any further. When trying the same but instead clicking 'Change API User', I get an error saying to contact SF support.

Has anyone come across this? Would you recommend deleting the connect app & permissions and starting fresh? Thanks!

Comment: I think if the wizard doesn't it's because it's run and been successful before. Have you hit the integrate option under your user record in MC?

Comment: Thanks @MattLacey! That would make sense then. Yes, the API user has been integrated in MC.

Comment: Update - I have removed removed Configuration Settings in Salesforce for Marketing Cloud Connect and am now instead getting a new error! Error:
IO Exception: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://xxx--preprod--et4ae5.visualforce.com/services/Soap/m/42.0

Comment: Have you added that remote site setting? That said, the wizard adds heaps for you, sound like it's in a bit of a confused state. Easiest option at this point may be to uninstall the package from the sandbox and re-install it - that'll clear out all it's data if you chose that option.

Comment: @AnjLivi -- when you see that error, you need to go into Remote Site Settings, find the "MetadataAPI" Remote Site, and replace the existing URL with the one that you provided above.

Comment: Thanks @lilDabz and Matt Lacey - SF support walked me through that exact fix, adding the endpoint in the error message to the Remote Site Settings.